# Add line to a row when hover

Tags: html, css

i hava problem.
This is my table:

[image]

This should be my table when I hover

[image]

If I now hover a row, it should have a color background and a line should be displayed on the side, which is a little thicker. 
The head area should not be highlighted in color. (head are = Produkt, Datum, Summe). 
How do I do that? With the following code I only have the individual rows highlighted in color and not the line. How the do I add the line and not hover the head area?

```
table.ordertable tr:hover {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
  padding: 10px 0; 
  border-width: 1px 0; 
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #badafc;
}
```

creating of the table

```
function showOrders(orderlist) {
  console.log(orderlist);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  table.className="ordertable";
  var thead = document.createElement("thead");
  var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  var headRow = document.createElement("tr");
  ["Produkt","Datum","Summe"].forEach(function(el) {
    var th=document.createElement("th");
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(el));
    headRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  thead.appendChild(headRow);
  table.appendChild(thead); 
  orderlist.forEach(function(el) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var o in el) {  
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(el[o]))
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);  
  });
  table.appendChild(tbody);             
  return table;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `border-left` property in your `css`

```
table.ordertable tr:hover {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #badafc;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;   <----- new property you can change color and strength by px
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) And how can I not have the hover displayed for the head area?

Comment: What class does `head area` have?

Comment: This is the class `table.ordertable th {
 border-width: 1px;
 padding: 8px;
  border-color: #FEFEFE;
}`

Comment: I'm creating the table via script. Please see mey edit! :)

Comment: @Marcel.david1 - put the first row into a thead, instead of the default tbody. Then, use `tbody > tr:hover` since you've now got `thead > tr` around your heading, you wont change the styles when hovering the first row.

Answer (score 0):

- Add this `border-bottom: 3px solid black;`
- like...

```
table.ordertable tr:hover {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
  padding: 10px 0; 
  border-width: 1px 0; 
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #badafc;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

Comment: (0) why the black bottom-border. (1) Where's the aqua left-border?

Comment: Thank you very much! 
And how can I not have the hover displayed for the head area?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the border `border-left`

```css
table.ordertable tr:hover {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    padding: 10px 0; 
    border-width: 1px 0; 
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #badafc;
    border-left: 5px solid blue; 
}
```

also to make sure that your header doesn't get the hover effect, add a class t-row to all the table rows, except the row containing header, and change your CSS  as following.

```css
table.ordertable tr.t-row:hover {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    padding: 10px 0; 
    border-width: 1px 0; 
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #badafc;
    border-left: 5px solid blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .table td,
    .table th {
      padding: 5px 10px
    }

    .table  tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    }

    .table tbody  tr {
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .table tbody  tr td:first-child:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 4px;
      background-color: #00A2E8;
      top: 0;
      border-radius: 5px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .table tbody tr:hover {
      background-color: #D5F2FF;
    }

    .table tbody tr:hover td:first-child:before {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Produkt</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Summe</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Burger Pommes</td>
        <td>20.05.2020</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pommes Wasser Coca Cola</td>
        <td>21.05.2020</td>
        <td>18</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```